# pager Duty oncall schedule

Tags: pagerduty

We have 7 team members, I want to create oncall schedule in Pager duty with below scenario

9 AM - 4 PM (Monday - Friday) single person, rotation everyday
4 PM - 2 AM (Monday - Sunday) single person rotation (weekly basis) so one person will be doing monday to friday

But the person oncall for the week from 4 PM - 2 AM cannot be part of 9 AM - 4 PM on any of the day for that week
How can I set this oncall schedule? I tried doing it with two layers but then the people overlaps for few occasions.